# Ruby: extract features of a Stack from the Array class

Tags: ruby, stack

I have the need to use a Stack-like data structure for a program that I am writing and I know that Ruby doesn't have an explicit Stack data-structure, but that the Array class has all of the properties that make a Stack: `push`, `pop`, `size`, `clear`, `isEmpty`, `inspect`, `to_s`.

In searching online I found various posts using this syntax to extract features of the Array class into a subclass:

```
Stack = Array.extract([
  :push,
  :pop,
  :size,
  :clear,
  :inspect,
  :to_s
])

s = Stack.new
s.push 1
s.push 2
s.push 3
s       # => [1, 2, 3]
s.pop   # => 3
s       # => [1, 2]
```

I would like to do something similar to this so my subclass of Array is restricted in what calls it can make, but it appears that the extract method is no longer in the Array class API.

Questions:

1. This feature was removed for a reason, what is the detriment of something like this?
2. How can achieve functionality similar to this using Ruby 1.9.3? Right now I am just delegating the calls that I need to the Array class, but all the other methods in the Array class can still be called on my Stack object, which I don't want to allow.

Comment: ["if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of that program."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). So by subclassing *and* removing most of the interface you'd have something that claims to be an Array but cannot be used in most places that expect an Array; the technical term for such a thing is *fully loaded foot gun*.

Comment: +1 @muistooshort. Overriding basic class behaviors is a really bad idea for many reasons, maintenance and debugging being the first two that would make me take a different path.

Comment: @muistooshort I am not seeing the problem, I am claiming to present to the user a Stack-like interface, the have no idea how the Stack is implemented. All they know is that they can do Stack-like things with it. What is the problem with that?

Comment: But if someone says `stack.is_a? Array` it will way "yes" even though it doesn't support the full Array interface. What you were planning is an abuse of subclassing. You'd be claiming to present an Array simply by subclassing.

Comment: @muistooshort: The Liskov Substitution Principle talks about *types*, not *classes*. Classes aren't types. They are simply a convenient vehicle for code reuse, nothing more. What the OP wants to do is perfectly fine. That's why you don't use `is_a?` for type checking: because it doesn't check the type, it checks the class.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: It may be fine in an academic sense but it is not fine in real code that has a job to do. If I saw something like that in a code review I'd send it back for a rewrite to avoid future problems.

Comment: @JörgWMittag How do you do type checking? Using `respond_to?`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take this code, for example:

```
class Stack
  def initialize
    @array = []
  end

  def push val
    @array.push val
  end

  def pop 
    @array.pop
  end
end
```

Here you have private instance var to which you delegate selected methods. Other methods cannot be called directly. The syntax can be sweetened and made more "rubesque" with some metaprogramming, but basic idea is as shown above.

Of course, one can always get to that private var via `instance_variable_get` and there's nothing you can do about it. This is Ruby!

Make clean safe public interface. And if someone tries to meddle with inner parts and breaks something, it's his problem.

#### Update

If you're using ActiveSupport (which comes with Rails), then there's a simpler way of doing this.

```
# load ActiveSupport if not in Rails env
require 'active_support/core_ext'

class Stack
  def initialize
    @impl = []
  end

  # the "extract" part :)
  delegate :count, :push, :pop, to: :@impl
end

s = Stack.new
s.push(3).push(4)
s.count # => 2
```

Or look at [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9898863/125816) by @AndrewGrimm.

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to be doing a lot of delegating, then you may want to use the delegation methods Ruby provides.

```
require "forwardable"

class Stack
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@array, :push, :pop

  def initialize
    @array = []
  end
end
```

Not only does it mean less typing, but if you're familiar with `Forwardable`, it's easier to read. You know that your class is merely delegating, without having to read the code for `Stack#push` or `Stack#pop`.

Comment: Thank you! This will let me remove at least four of the methods from the class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can undefine methods that you don't like, although it looks wired.

```
class Stack < Array
  DISLIKE_IMS = instance_methods - Object.instance_methods - [:public, :pop, :size, :to_s, :inspect, :clear]
  DISLIKE_CMS = methods - Object.methods

  DISLIKE_IMS.each do |im|
    class_eval "undef #{im}"
  end

  DISLIKE_CMS.each do |cm|
    instance_eval "undef #{cm}"
  end
end
```

Comment: One should **NOT** do this. Doing so violates [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It seems that `Array` should be a subtype of `Stack`, what I'm doing is taking advantages from `Array`, or stealing methods from `Array`. Is there a way to extract those methods into a module and mixin to the `Stack` ?