# Troubles mixing in the #Array and #Enumerable class to my custom class

Tags: ruby, class, mixins

I am trying to mixin the #Array and #Enumerable classes into my custom class so that I can use the push, pop, size and inject methods (and maybe some other ones). I tried to use `include Array` as well as `class RPNCalculator < Array` which I thought was the proper syntax, but got the error:

```
home/action/12_rpn_calculator.rb:2:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
```

So I tried using `module Array` and it seems to be running but not grabbing the methods. So I am really confused. Here is my code:

```
class RPNCalculator 
  include Array 

  attr_accessor :calculator, :result


  def initialize
    @calculator = []
    @result = 0
  end

  #def push(*num)
    #@calculator.push(*num)
  #end

  def has_enough #check if there are enough args
    if @calculator.count < 2
      raise "calculator is empty"
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end

  def result  
  end

  def get_nums(source) #get as many numbers as needed from array for method
    calculate = []
    source.map{|n| calculate << n.pop}
    calculate
  end

  def plus
    if has_enough then get_nums(@calculator).inject(:+) end  
  end

  def minus
  end

  def divide
  end

  def times
  end

  end
```

Why am I not able to get it to run using `include Array` or `class Myclass < Array` ?

Here is the rspec in case it helps:

```
require_relative "12_rpn_calculator"


    describe RPNCalculator do

  attr_accessor :calculator

  before do
    @calculator = RPNCalculator.new
  end

  it "adds two numbers" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.plus
    calculator.value.should == 5
  end

  it "adds three numbers" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.push(4)
    calculator.plus
    calculator.value.should == 7
    calculator.plus
    calculator.value.should == 9
  end

  it "subtracts the second number from the first number" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.minus
    calculator.value.should == -1
  end

  it "adds and subtracts" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.push(4)
    calculator.minus
    calculator.value.should == -1
    calculator.plus
    calculator.value.should == 1
  end

  it "multiplies and divides" do
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.push(4)
    calculator.divide
    calculator.value.should == (3.0 / 4.0)
    calculator.times
    calculator.value.should == 2.0 * (3.0 / 4.0)
  end

  it "resolves operator precedence unambiguously" do
    # 1 2 + 3 * => (1 + 2) * 3
    calculator.push(1)
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.plus
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.times
    calculator.value.should == (1+2)*3

    @calculator = RPNCalculator.new
    # 1 2 3 * + => 1 + (2 * 3)
    calculator.push(1)
    calculator.push(2)
    calculator.push(3)
    calculator.times
    calculator.plus
    calculator.value.should == 1+(2*3)
  end

  it "fails informatively when there's not enough values stacked away" do
    expect {
      calculator.plus
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")

    expect {
      calculator.minus
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")

    expect {
      calculator.times
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")

    expect {
      calculator.divide
    }.to raise_error("calculator is empty")
  end

  # extra credit
  it "tokenizes a string" do
    calculator.tokens("1 2 3 * + 4 5 - /").should ==
      [1, 2, 3, :*, :+, 4, 5, :-, :/]
  end

  # extra credit
  it "evaluates a string" do
    calculator.evaluate("1 2 3 * +").should ==
      ((2 * 3) + 1)

    calculator.evaluate("4 5 -").should ==
      (4 - 5)

    calculator.evaluate("2 3 /").should ==
      (2.0 / 3.0)

    calculator.evaluate("1 2 3 * + 4 5 - /").should ==
      (1.0 + (2 * 3)) / (4 - 5)
  end

end
```

Comment: Subclassing array should be possible, although it seems to me that having an array instance variable to represent the stack is the better design choice

Comment: yes i ended up just doing that. turns out it was easier, lol

Answer (score 0):

Simply write your custom pop/push methods, because if the datatype handled is an Array type then pop and push will be available.

[Ruby: extract features of a Stack from the Array class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874897/ruby-extract-features-of-a-stack-from-the-array-class)

Comment: I got an error when I tried both `include Array` and `RPNCalculator < Array` as I tried both before I used module. I thought that was the proper way to do it. Why do think I am getting the error? WIll check out the link as well...

Comment: Array is a class and not a module.

Comment: I agree. But as I said (I just tried it again) I am getting this error: `/home/action/12_rpn_calculator.rb:2:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError) `

Comment: I am coding locally, but I will update my answer to give you both the complete .rb (using include)and the .rspec ...gimmie a sec

Comment: I understand, your using rspec to test a single file of code. Don't make drastic changes to your original question. I'd use a Gist to share: https://gist.github.com/

Comment: I see you're using the 'include Array', the error is on line two, which is where you are including the Array class (not a module). The module you want is the Forwardable module. Refer to the docs http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html

Comment: Your probably right about making drastic changes but I figured the original question was perhaps confusing because It had the 'include module' which distracted from what I really wanted to know which is, bottom line...why include wasn't working ;)

Comment: require Array got me this error: /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': no implicit conversion of Class into String (Ty
peError)

Comment: That's ok, the edit was good. Happy coding and I have no doubt you'll be a great full stack developer as Ruby was a smart language to choose.

Comment: Thanks @wurde for the encouraging words, I love Ruby -  the learning curve is driving me nuts. lol...but Ruby is awesome :)